# Bad graphics without nomodeset on in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia, nomodeset

When I installed the OS, the screen was flickering making it virtually non-usable. I put nomodeset in the grub file and it stopped, but now I can't do things like dual-screen or use a night light even because of that setting.

Edit: Results from `lshw -C videos`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: `nomodeset` is for **temporarily** boot in low graphics mode so you can install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: We don't know what graphics you have (except probably nvidia because you tagged it).  `sudo lshw -C video` will list-hardware of class=video and provide details of what the kernel has detected and driver being used (which will be impacted by nomodeset).  Did you follow any documentation on adding drivers (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/hardware.html.en https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/hardware-problems-graphics.html.en https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia, ttps://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nvidia) or try to change drivers as in DriverHowto/Nvidia?

Comment: @guiverc So I edited in the results from ´lshw -C video´. I haven't done much to the drivers except change between those listed in the additional drivers section of software update. Right now it says no drivers available. Should i download and install the latest driver from the Nvidia website?

Comment: No, do not install from Nvidia binaries. First disable Secure Boot and if nit already reinstall the recommended version in Additional Drivers.

Comment: The Intel Graphics us also unclaimed which suggests further problems.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I was already off, and I reinstalled the drivers from aditional drivers. So now the laptop screen is turned on completely black, and the only way I can use the laptop is through HDMI to another monitor.